# Vortex energy calculation in contour integral

Tags: quantum-field-theory, integration, complex-numbers, many-body

I encountered a problem asking me to calculating the contour integral to evaluate the energy of a vortex as shown in the picture. I am asked to compute the energy using the following equation.
$$E=-\frac{J}{2} n^{2} \operatorname{Re} \oint_{\mathcal{C}} \mathrm{d} z \frac{\arg z}{z},$$
I think I just need to compute the bigger loop integral minus the smaller loop integral.
So I let $z_{1}=Re^{i\omega t}$$z_{2}=r_{0}e^{i\omega t}$, then $\oint\mathrm{d} z \frac{\arg z}{z}$ can be converted to $\oint i\omega^{2}t dt$, which yield the result $2\pi^{2}i$, and taking the real part I simply get nothing, which does not lead to the result. Anyone know where did this go wrong?

[image]

Comment: I think you are taking a branch cut of the power function on the positive real axis, in which case you need to take $\mathrm{arg}(z)=2\pi-\epsilon$ on the lower path along to the real axis.